# DHCP lease expires on WPA2 Enterprise network (UPC Wi-free)

Tags: wireless, 17.10, dhcp, wpa2

I'm often connecting to a popular network of hotspots created by my ISP (UPC's Wi-free, like Fon). It's a WPA2 enterprise network with MSCHAPv2 auth. It used to work fine.

Lately, however, I have been experiencing **frequent disconnections related to DHCP lease expiring**. The physical wifi connection remains active but the interface loses its IP address and I lose the connection to the Internet.

```
 dhclient[25316]: DHCPREQUEST of 203.0.113.17 on wlp2s0 to 10.177.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x55c8a752)
 dhclient[25316]: message repeated 2 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 203.0.113.17 on wlp2s0 to 10.177.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x55c8a752)]
 dhclient[25316]: DHCPREQUEST of 203.0.113.17 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x55c8a752)
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514411098.7236] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> expire
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514411098.7563] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 25316
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514411098.7564] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed expire -> done
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514411098.7578] device (wlp2s0): scheduling DHCPv4 restart in 120 seconds, 3 tries left (reason: lease expired)
 avahi-daemon[1021]: Withdrawing address record for 203.0.113.17 on wlp2s0.
```

Not every lease renewal fails

```
 dhclient[25316]: DHCPREQUEST of 203.0.113.17 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x55c8a752)
 dhclient[25316]: DHCPACK of 203.0.113.17 from 62.179.2.155
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0094] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 203.0.113.17
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0095] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 25 (255.255.255.128)
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0096] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 203.0.113.12
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0096] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 60
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0096] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   hostname 'thisubuntulaptop'
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0097] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '62.179.1.60'
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0097] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '62.179.1.61'
 dbus[1066]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0098] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   domain name 'chello.pl'
 NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0098] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound
 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
 dhclient[25316]: bound to 203.0.113.17 -- renewal in 25 seconds.
```

but they often do and since the lease time is only 60 seconds, this causes very frequent interruptions.

**How can I identify the cause and prevent these renewals failures from occurring?**

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the problem. The DHCP server at the other end has set the `lease time 60` `DHCP` option. This is usually done when an Admin is making changes to the `DHCP` tables. Maybe "my ISP (UPC's Wi-free, like Fon)"'s support could help you. What actually happens is, that after 60 seconds, your IP address lease expires. When your laptop tries to renew the lease, it times out. Thus, the error. You might be able to use my `net-o-matic` script `git clone ://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git` - Watch for network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

Comment: @waltinator My ISP's support tested the connection on their device with my credentials and it worked fine for them. How can I produce some sort of log showing their DHCP server is malfunctioning? This would be helpful.

Comment: Their `DHCP` server is not "malfunctioning", is just configured strangely. However, the log entry you posted here, especially the lines `dhclient[25316]: DHCPACK of 203.0.113.17 from 62.179.2.155` (shows which server answered your request, and `NetworkManager[23498]: <info>  [1514410926.0096] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 60`. It IS possible they do this on purpose. You could change the values for `scheduling DHCPv4 restart in 120 seconds, 3 tries left`, see `man dhclient.conf`. But see my `net-o-matic` script. It watches for "Net going down" and does a user-defined command to fix it.

Comment: I think your problem is "Network Connection Going Down", not "DHCP Lease Expires".

Comment: @waltinator So the connection does go down which is why the renewal isn't happening rather than the lease not being renewed taking the connection down? How can I tell?

Comment: see my net-o-matic script

Comment: @waltinator I don't understand your comments or what I should be looking for/at in your script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70879/discussion-between-waltinator-and-damn-terminal).